# Using macros in C to define data structures

Tags: c

I am trying to wrap my head around the concept of using macros to define data structure operations. The following code is a simple example to use the built in list library in FreeBSD. In the library all operations are defined as macros. I have seen this approach in couple of other libraries also.

I can see that this has some advantages eg. being ability to use any data structure as an element in the list. But I do not quite understand how this works. For example:

1. What is `stailhead`? This seems to be "just" defined.
2. How to pass `head` and `entries` to a function?
3. What type is `head`, how can I declare a pointer to it?

Is there a standard name for  this technique which I can use to search google, or any book which explains this concept? Any links or good explanation as to how this technique works will be much appreciated.

Thanks to [Niklas B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/916657/niklas-b) I ran `gcc -E` and got this definition for `head`

```
struct stailhead {
  struct stailq_entry *stqh_first;
  struct stailq_entry **stqh_last; 
} head = { ((void *)0), &(head).stqh_first };
```

and this for `stailq_entry`

```
struct stailq_entry {
 int value;
 struct { struct stailq_entry *stqe_next; } entries;
};
```

So I guess `head` is of type `struct stailhead`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/queue.h>

struct stailq_entry {
        int value;
        STAILQ_ENTRY(stailq_entry) entries;
};

int main(void)
{
        STAILQ_HEAD(stailhead, stailq_entry) head = STAILQ_HEAD_INITIALIZER(head);
        struct stailq_entry *n1;
        unsigned i;
        STAILQ_INIT(&head);                     /* Initialize the queue. */

        for (i=0;i<10;i++){
                n1 = malloc(sizeof(struct stailq_entry));   /* Insert at the head. */
                n1->value = i;
                STAILQ_INSERT_HEAD(&head, n1, entries);
        }
        n1 = NULL;

        while (!STAILQ_EMPTY(&head)) {
                n1 = STAILQ_LAST(&head, stailq_entry, entries);
                STAILQ_REMOVE(&head, n1, stailq_entry, entries);
                printf ("n2: %d\n", n1->value);
                free(n1);
        }

        return (0);
}
```

Comment: Go to the appropriate headers and see what do `STAILQ_HEAD`, `STAILQ_INIT` expand to

Comment: Or just use `gcc -E`. BTW, this way of using macros is useful to simulate generics in C.

Comment: At first look, I believe using STAILQ_HEAD_INITIALIZER in the definition, and later STAILQ_INIT is redundant.  I believe they do the same thing.

Comment: There is a followup up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039650)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First read [this](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/STAILQ_HEAD/) to get a hold what these macros do. And then go to `queue.h`. You'll get your treasure trove there!

I found a few gold coins for you-

```
#define STAILQ_HEAD(name, type)                                         \
struct name {                                                           \
        struct type *stqh_first;/* first element */                     \
        struct type **stqh_last;/* addr of last next element */         \
}
```

Lets dig in a bit deep and answer your questions

> What is stailhead? This seems to be "just" defined.

```
#define STAILQ_HEAD(name, type)                                         \
struct name {                                                           \
        struct type *stqh_first;/* first element */                     \
        struct type **stqh_last;/* addr of last next element */         \
}
 STAILQ_HEAD(stailhead, entry) head =
 STAILQ_HEAD_INITIALIZER(head);
 struct stailhead *headp;            /* Singly-linked tail queue head. */
```

So `stailhead` is a structure

> How to pass head and entries to a function?

```
#define STAILQ_ENTRY(type)                                              \
struct {                                                                \
        struct type *stqe_next; /* next element */                      \
}
```

So `entries` and `head` ( as explained before ) are just structures and you can pass them just as you pass other structures. `&structure_variable`

> What type is head, how can I declare a pointer to it?

Already explained!

Read [this man page](http://leaf.dragonflybsd.org/cgi/web-man?section=3&command=queue) for nice pretty examples.

Comment: `man 3 queue` (XXX stupid padding to make stackoverflow accept my comment)

Comment: Thanks Pavan, Thanks for taking time to answer me. Your answers are really helpful.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Raj! I am just doing my SO job :). Glad it helped you :)