# incompatible pointer type - why?

Tags: c

I am trying to understand the inner workings of [queue (3)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=queue&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%209.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) macros in Freebsd. I had asked a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031665) about the same topic and this is a follow up question to it.

I am trying to define a function to insert an element into the queue. [queue (3)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=queue&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%209.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) provides the macro `STAILQ_INSERT_HEAD` which needs a pointer to the head of the queue, type of the items in queue and the item to be inserted. My problem is that I am getting

```
stailq.c:31: warning: passing argument 1 of 'addelement' from incompatible pointer type
```

error when I try to pass the address of `head` to the function. The full source code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/queue.h>

struct stailq_entry {
        int value;
        STAILQ_ENTRY(stailq_entry) entries;
};

STAILQ_HEAD(stailhead, stailq_entry);

int addelement(struct stailhead *h1, int e){
        struct stailq_entry *n1;
        n1 = malloc(sizeof(struct stailq_entry));
        n1->value = e;
        STAILQ_INSERT_HEAD(h1, n1, entries);
        return (0);
}
int main(void)
{
        STAILQ_HEAD(stailhead, stailq_entry) head = STAILQ_HEAD_INITIALIZER(head);
        struct stailq_entry *n1;
        unsigned i;
        STAILQ_INIT(&head);                     /* Initialize the queue. */

        for (i=0;i<10;i++){
                addelement(&head, i);
        }
        n1 = NULL;

        while (!STAILQ_EMPTY(&head)) {
                n1 = STAILQ_LAST(&head, stailq_entry, entries);
                STAILQ_REMOVE(&head, n1, stailq_entry, entries);
                printf ("n2: %d\n", n1->value);
                free(n1);
        }

        return (0);
}
```

As far as I can tell, `head` is of type `struct stailhead` and the `addelement` function also expects a pointer to `struct stailhead`.

`STAILQ_HEAD(stailhead, stailq_entry);` expands to:

```
struct stailhead {
  struct stailq_entry *stqh_first;
  struct stailq_entry **stqh_last; 
};
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: It may have something to do with the fact that you're calling the STAILQ_HEAD macro twice, thus redefining the struct. Don't do that. Just declare head as a struct of the desired type (i.e., "struct stailhead head;"). These macros are not namespace-side-effect-free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to convert the first line in your `main` function from

```
STAILQ_HEAD(stailhead, stailq_entry) head = STAILQ_HEAD_INITIALIZER(head);
```

to

```
struct stailhead head = STAILQ_HEAD_INITIALIZER(head);
```

What's happening is that `STAILQ_HEAD` is a macro that defines a new type, a struct that is your data structure with the name of the first parameter with an entry type of the second parameter.

You're only supposed to call `STAILQ_HEAD` once to define the *type* of the struct - then you use that typename from thereon to create new data structures of this type.

What you did in your code sample is simple: you defined a struct named `stailhead` twice - once in the global scope and once in the scope of your `main` function. You were then passing a pointer to the local `stailhead` to a function that accepted the global type with the same name.

Even though both structs are identical, they're in two different storage scopes and the compiler treats them as distinct types. It's warning you that you're converting from type `main::stailhead` to type `global::stailhead` (note that I have just made up this notation, I do not believe it is canon).

You only need to define `stailhead` by calling the `STAILQ_HEAD` macro just once at the top of the file where you already did, and from thereon use `struct stailhead` to define an object of this type.

Comment: You're most welcome. Opening the header file and looking at the macro definitions is usually a good way to gain further understanding for what's taking place behind the scenes and debug macro mysteries.