# How to receive unnamed structures as function parameters in C?

Tags: c, struct, function-prototypes, function-parameter

Yesterday while going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031665/using-macros-in-c-to-define-data-structures/) question, I found a curious case of passing and receiving unnamed structures as function parameters.

For example, if I have a structure like this,

```
int main ()
{
    struct {
        int a;
    } var;

    fun(&var);
}
```

Now, what should the prototype of `fun` be? And how can I use that structure *as a structure(pointer)* in the function `fun`?

Comment: There is no good reason to do that. A `struct` which is passed (even as pointer) to some function really *should be named* and declared. Keeping it anonymous is bad coding practice. Of course, you could declare your function as having a `void*` formal parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For alignment reasons, this prototype should work:

```
void fun(int *x);
```

And of course:

```
void fun(void *x);
```

I don't see an easy way to actually use the structure effectively in the function; perhaps declare it again inside that function and then assign the `void *` ?

#### EDIT as requested

> *6.7.2.1 - 15*
>
> **A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its
> initial member** (or if that member is a bit-ﬁeld, then to the unit in
> which it resides), and vice versa.  There may be unnamed padding
> within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

Comment: `void *` should be fine. BUt why `int*`? It'll generate an incompatible pointer type warning in C and an error in C++. I dint get your "alignment reasons" part

Comment: @PavanManjunath I added a quote for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also define `fun` as `void fun(void* opaque);`. This is however not considered a good practice as declaring the parameter as `void*` will strip it down of any type information. You will also need to interpret the parameter passed, as you will end up with a pointer to a sequence of bytes. You will have to pass the size of the structure somehow too.

This practice is common in the WIN32 API, where you have a field in the structure that specifies the size of the structure (usually named dwSize or similar). This can also help conveying information about the version of the structure definition.

Another thing to consider here is [structure packing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537964/visual-c-equivalent-of-gccs-attribute-packed), which is compiler- and platform-dependent.