# Is there a way to pass a struct without an explicitly named type as an argument to a function?

Tags: c, function, struct, arguments

Let's say we have the following a struct defined as follows:

```
struct
{
    int  month;
    int  day;
    int  year;
} date;
```

Could I somehow implement a function that took as an argument a struct of the same type as date, even though it hasn't been named explicitly? In other words, would I be able to make a function call to some random function like `randomFunction (date)`? In that case, how would the header of that function look like, since there is no name for the struct type of `date`?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Look to `...` or pass by its address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forward declaring a typedef of an unnamed struct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249548/forward-declaring-a-typedef-of-an-unnamed-struct)

Comment: dupe/related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040369/how-to-receive-unnamed-structures-as-function-parameters-in-c

Comment: Think yourself: How would you declare the function parameter to pass the `struct`? And how would the compiler know about the members?

Comment: @chux: `...`? How would you invoke `va_arg`?

Comment: @Keith Thompson OP has not detailed what the function is to do, so `va_arg()` and the oddities of using it with `Rivero_foo()` are TBD and if  possible and/or if needed.  As it stands, OP can use `printf("", data);` with no ill effects.  Such a call can be useful to _use_ data in code to preserve from from being optimization out.  Maybe it is a an embedded copy right notice, etc.

Comment: @chux: Whatever problem the OP is having, it's vanishingly unlikely that passing the anonymous struct to a variadic function is the solution. Naming the struct is almost certainly what the OP needs to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the struct type for date and call it within the program by using `date`

```
typedef struct date{
    int  month;
    int  day;
    int  year;
} date;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do it indirectly (for example you could pass a `void*` pointer that points to an object of the type, and then *somehow* access the members of the structure within the function).

A variadic function declared with `, ...` wouldn't work, since you still have to specify the name of the type when invoking `va_arg()`.

No, there's no direct way to do that. A function parameter has to be of some named type. And none of the indirect ways of doing it, frankly, are worth doing.

If you want to pass an argument of some `struct` type to a function, just give the type a name.